# Merge deep objects and override

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to merge two objects and override first object content with second object content.

I tried **undescore**`_.extend()` but the result is not what I want.

### **e.g**

**Objects :**

```
var a = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": {
        "zipCode": "75000",
        "city": "Paris"
    }
};

var b = {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "address": {
        "zipCode": "99999"
    }
};

merge(a, b); /* fake function */
```

**Expected result :**

```
var a = {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": {
        "zipCode": "99999",
        "city": "Paris"
    }
};
```

I also tried modules like [merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge) but it did not suit me.
How could I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```js
Object.deepExtend = function(destination, source) {
  for (var property in source) {
     if (typeof source[property] === "object" &&
       source[property] !== null ) {
       destination[property] = destination[property] || {};
       arguments.callee(destination[property], source[property]);
     } else {
       destination[property] = source[property];
     }
  }
};


var a = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": {
        "zipCode": "75000",
        "city": "Paris"
    }
};

var b = {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "address": {
        "zipCode": "99999"
    }
};

Object.deepExtend(a,b);

console.dir(a);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly ! I also found that __lodash__ `_.merge()` is doing the same

Comment: @auk - Good to hear that